# How to send data as object name from Fragment to Activity

Tags: kotlin

I have to send my object name `"rrbQuestiontObject"` to a `QuizQuestionActivity`

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        val text :TextView=view.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
        text.setOnClickListener (){
            val intent = Intent(getActivity(), QuizQuestionActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment -

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
val text :TextView=view.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
text.setOnClickListener (){
    val intent = Intent(getActivity(), QuizQuestionActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("rrbQuestiontObject" , value)
    startActivity(intent)
}

return view
}
```

In QuizQuestionActivity inside onCreate() -

```
 val intent = getIntent();
 val myValue = intent.getStringExtra("rrbQuestiontObject")
 Log.d(TAG,"QuizQuestionActivity - "+myValue)
```